# Find Matching Data and Paste onto Next Empty Cell on the same row

Tags: vba

I am new here. I have been trying to solve this problem but to no avail. 
My objectives are:

1) Need to find matching cell in the Installment workbook and paste the data into the next empty cell on the same row as the matching cell. The matching cell will come from Column E.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim itemNumber As String
Dim itemAmount As Single
Dim myData As Workbook

Worksheets("sheet1").Select
itemNumber = Range("B6")
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
itemAmount = Range("H16")

Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Mydata\Installment.xlsx")
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E1").Select

For Each cell In Range(“E2:E10000”)
IF cell.Value = itemNumber Then
Cellvalue = ActiveCell.address
Next
End IF
ColumnCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("Cellvalue").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("Cellvalue")
.Offset(0, ColumnCount) = itemNumber
.End With
myData.Save
Workbooks("Installment.xlsx").Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should work.  I've made a few "tweaks" to your code, primarily removing the "select" statements, which are usually undesirable and unnecessary.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim itemNumber As String
    Dim itemAmount As Single
    Dim myData As Workbook
    Dim Wk As Worksheet
    Dim Cel As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        itemNumber = .Range("B6").Value
        itemAmount = .Range("H16").Value
    End With

    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Mydata\Installment.xlsx")

    Set Wk = myData.Worksheets("sheet1")
    For Each Cel In Wk.Range("E2:E10000")
        If Cel.Value = itemNumber Then
            Cel.Value = Cel.Address
    '       get next blank cell in row
            Wk.Cells(Cel.Row, Wk.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Value = itemNumber
        End If
    Next

    myData.Close True 'save & close

    End Sub
```